# Can I fly with an empty fuel bottle in checked baggage in Europe (Icelandair, UK→IS)?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security, icelandair

In the USA, the [FAA permits bringing an empty fuel bottle](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/hazmat_safety/more_info/?hazmat=41).

I'm flying between the United Kingdom and Iceland on Icelandair.  Can I bring an empty fuel bottle in checked baggage?  It does have big "danger" signs on it.

[image: fuel bottle]
Image from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EONU43Q).

Comment: I'd make sure it has zero smell, if a TSA agent decides to open it and smells gasoline or kerosene then it would likely be confiscated.

Comment: @Tom Yes.  I'm washing them several days in advance, then keep them open for those days as well as during transport (so the agent can tell immediately that it's empty).

Comment: Other than simply washing and airing out, it might be a good idea to be able to assure the airline that the container has (at some point in time since it contained fuel) been _completely full of water_, which would have pushed any leftover fumes out more securely than rinsing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Icelandair's website, under [Baggage restrictions](https://www.icelandair.ca/information/baggage-information/baggage-restrictions/reference-guide/), "*Camping stoves and fuel containers that have contained a flammable liquid fuel, with empty fuel tank and/or fuel container*" are "*permitted in or as checked baggage*", **but** the "*approval of Icelandair is required*". This statement is followed by a big button to open a "Contact Icelandair" form.